# Python 2D self-avoiding random walk

Tags: python, random-walk

I want to make a self-avoiding 2D random walk in python. Imagine it like the dot is on the square grid and it can only go up, down, left or right but it cannot land twice on the same point.  I have an idea how to do it, but my programming skills aren't very good (I'm a beginner) and the code doesn't work.

The end product should look something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSnme.png)

My idea was to create two lists: one where I store x and y (i.e. the coordinates I've already been to) and one with the points that are around the point I'm currently at (I marked it as neighbors). I want to create a new variable surviving_neighbors. This would be a list of coordinates of the surrounding points where I have not yet been to (e.g. I am currently at (1,1); I have already been at (0,1) and (1,2) so that my surviving neighbors would be (1,0 ) and (2,1)). I want to get Surviving_neighbors using the difference method: I put neighbors.difference(list of coordinates) and save in a variable what is in the list of neighbors, but not in the list of coordinates I was on. The first problem I have is that I don't have one list with coordinates, but x and y are stored separately. Next, I would use choice(surviving_neighbors) and thus choose new coordinates. This creates another problem: I probably won't be able to call it a trajectory, but I'll have to define it again in terms of x and y...
The teacher suggested that I store x and y as vectors, but I have no idea how to do that.

### Code:

```
from random import choice
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.style.use(['science', 'notebook', 'dark background'])

x, y = 0, 0

coordinates = [(x, y)]
for time in range(10):
    dx, dy = choice([(0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1)])
    x, y = x + dx, y + dy
    X.append(x)
    Y.append(y)

    neighbors = [x+1, y
                 x-1
                 y
                 x, y+1
                 x, y-1]

    surviving_neighbors = neighbors.difference(X, Y)
    trajectory = choice(surviving_neighbors)

    plt.plot()
```

Comment: "the code doesn't work" is not a very informative problem description. Please explain what you mean by that.

Comment: Can you make sure your indentation in the question matches your program?

Comment: In your code `X` and `Y` are never defined. Also -- lists don't have a `difference` method. Sets do -- although even in that case `.difference(X,Y)` is unlikely to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know where you are going with this, here is a basic working example;

This is invalid as they don't exist;

> ```
> plt.style.use(['science', 'notebook', 'dark background'])
> ```

Possible values are;

> ['Solarize_Light2', '_classic_test_patch', '_mpl-gallery',
> '_mpl-gallery-nogrid', 'bmh', 'classic', 'dark_background', 'fast',
> 'fivethirtyeight', 'ggplot', 'grayscale', 'seaborn-v0_8',
> 'seaborn-v0_8-bright', 'seaborn-v0_8-colorblind', 'seaborn-v0_8-dark',
> 'seaborn-v0_8-dark-palette', 'seaborn-v0_8-darkgrid',
> 'seaborn-v0_8-deep', 'seaborn-v0_8-muted', 'seaborn-v0_8-notebook',
> 'seaborn-v0_8-paper', 'seaborn-v0_8-pastel', 'seaborn-v0_8-poster',
> 'seaborn-v0_8-talk', 'seaborn-v0_8-ticks', 'seaborn-v0_8-white',
> 'seaborn-v0_8-whitegrid', 'tableau-colorblind10']

```
from random import choice
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-v0_8-darkgrid')
print(plt.style.available)

#2D self-avoiding random walk
def dotty(n):
    x, y = 0, 0
    path = [(x, y)]
    for i in range(n):
        # pick the closest point but it must complete without crossing itself
        x, y = choice([(x+1, y), (x-1, y), (x, y+1), (x, y-1)])
        if (x, y) in path:
            return path
        path.append((x, y))
    return path

# show plot
def show_path(path):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    # draw points
    plt.scatter(*zip(*path), s=5, c='k')
    # draw lines in red
    plt.plot(*zip(*path), c='r')
    plt.show()

# main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = dotty(100000)
    show_path(path)
```

Output:

[image: OUTPUT]